# Regex not working for omission of specific character string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am currently using this regex to isolate 5 digit values not preceded/followed by a number, a dash, and a period. I am trying to figure out a way in addition, to account for - also excluding those that contain a WO or PO with case sensitivity in mind. I just have tried different variations on where to put SO AND PO as a conditions to check against but fail at every turn.

```
(?<![-0-9.])[0-9]{5}(?![-0-9.])
```

Current output - Not desired

```
asdkjflsdf 12345     good
asdfsdf 1234asdfsdf  bad
12345                good
.12345.              bad
-12345               bad
SO 12345             good
123456 ppp           bad
1234                 bad
PO12345              good <--
Wo 12345             good <--
```

Output - Desired

```
asdkjflsdf 12345     good
asdfsdf 1234asdfsdf  bad
12345                good
.12345.              bad
-12345               bad
SO 12345             good
123456 ppp           bad
1234                 bad
PO12345              bad <--
Wo 12345             bad <--
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. Lookbehinds have to be fixed length, so you can't have a negative lookbehind that matches `PO` or `WO` with any amount of whitespace. And you can't combine this with the lookbehind for digit/period/dash, since that's a different length.

Comment: The pattern here is not really easily determined so you could end up using one or more checks. Are you trying to filter through already establish datasets or are these potential inputs on a website form/etc.

Comment: Why is `1234asdfsdf` good? And what lang/tool you're using? Where can the string contain `WO`/`PO` only before the number, alo after the number, anywhere?

Comment: is it sufficient to find everything and then have a second exclusionary round? often multiple rounds to narrow (or include additional) results leads to a faster (to run and develop) and more understandable solution than trying to have a single extremely complex regex

Comment: Sorry I changed that one to bad @bobblebubble - I am trying this out in powershell. ti7 yes I think that could work?

Comment: @Barmar In this case language matters. You actually can use a variable-length lookbehind in Kotlin, Perl, and potentially some other languages.

Comment: How about: [`(?i)(?<![-0-9.]|[pw]o[^\w\n]*)[0-9]{5}(?![-0-9.])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28%3f%3c!%5b-0-9.%5d%7c%5bpw%5do%5b%5e%5cw%5cn%5d*%29%5b0-9%5d%7b5%7d%28%3f!%5b-0-9.%5d%29&i=asdkjflsdf+12345+++++good%0d%0aasdfsdf+1234asdfsdf++bad%0d%0a12345++++++++++++++++good%0d%0a.12345.++++++++++++++bad%0d%0a-12345+++++++++++++++bad%0d%0aSO+12345+++++++++++++good%0d%0a123456+ppp+++++++++++bad%0d%0a1234+++++++++++++++++bad%0d%0aPO12345++++++++++++++bad+%3c--%0d%0aWo+12345+++++++++++++bad+%3c--)

Comment: Not even close @bobblebubble

Comment: [demo](https://tio.run/##RczNCoJAFAXgfU9xo0CNRvqHoDCIgjYZtWgxTTHpiJk6Q6O4KJ/d1NQ2d85893AFT9hLusz3s0yh0n56ji9tB4aj8WSq9FuFOTVUueBmr5dJLyJq8GT@D5RhBkKI@le8B7MpnPm/vOaBoOGeBgzOZqdy@LQAtvy1oZaLzLvHrAjeOQFgIa1YRjzgpRJY/RxgF4o4giV0bxUcmYz9nwAKaGS5oKjGQ1ONRRujAZrr5INFQji@XpJLSHoazpG8p6lq1AVNKY@l@Uyz7As) (using @mklement0 sample data) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a much simpler regex and then have a second round excluding the undesirable collections

Round 1 (exactly 5 digits with a word boundary)

```
^.*\b\d{5}\b.*$
```

Round 2 (exclude any unwanted matches)

```
[WwPp][Oo]            simple search (discard matches)
^((?![WwPp][Oo]).)*$  reject lookahead (keep matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

A two-pass approach, as [ti7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4541045/ti7) suggests, may indeed offer the simplest solution:

```bash
'asdkjflsdf 12345',
'asdfsdf 1234asdfsdf',
'12345',
'.12345.',
'-12345',
'SO 12345',
'123456 ppp',
'1234',
'PO12345',
'Wo 12345',
'CompanName WO# 12345' |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Input = $_
      Result = $_ -match '(?<![-0-9.])[0-9]{5}(?![-0-9.])' -and $_ -notmatch '[wp]o'
    }
  }
```

Output:

```bash
Input                Result
-----                ------
asdkjflsdf 12345       True
asdfsdf 1234asdfsdf   False
12345                  True
.12345.               False
-12345                False
SO 12345               True
123456 ppp            False
1234                  False
PO12345               False
Wo 12345              False
CompanName WO# 12345  False
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you can use

```
$s -match '(?<![-0-9.])(?<![pw]o[\W_]*)[0-9]{5}(?![-0-9.])'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQM8dV/2).

There are two negative lookbehinds added:

- `(?<![-0-9.])` - immediately to the left, there should be no ASCII digit, `-` or `.` chars
- `(?<![pw]o[\W_]*)` - immediately before the current location, there should be no `PO` or `WO` (case insensitive) substrings (as `-match` matches in a case insensitive way) followed with any zero or more non-alphanumeric chars
- `[0-9]{5}` - five ASCII digits
- `(?![-0-9.])` - immediately to the right, there should be no `-`, `.` or an ASCII digit.

Comment: CompanName WO# 12345 still sneaking through

Comment: This almost works CompanName WO# 12345 still sneaks through . The # is the culprit. Any character before the number throws it off

Comment: @DreDay Sorry, it is very late. I see you indicated the programming environment, so here is an updated  solution: `$s -match '(?<![-0-9.])(?<![pw]o[\W_]*)[0-9]{5}(?![-0-9.])'`